# Oracle comparing data between 2 tables

Tags: oracle, left-join

I am having 2 tables like below:

### Table1:

| PP | CP | LINNUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 18961-060 | 900000021 |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 22873 | 900000028 |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 |

### Table2:

| PP | CP | LINNUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 18961-060 | 900000021 |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 22873 | 900000028 |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 |

I am using following query to compare PP,CP columns from both tables and check if linnum matches or not. I have total of 126 entries in both tables and expecting output with 126 entries.

```
select a.pp,a.cp,a.linnum,b.pp,b.pp,b.linnum,
case when a.pp=b.pp and a.cp=b.cp and a.linnum=b.linnum then 'Y' Else 'N' end matchnomatch
from tt1 a inner join tt2 b
on (a.pp=b.pp and a.cp=b.cp);
```

### OUTPUT:

| A.PP | A.CP | A.LINNUM | B.PP | B.CP | B.LINNUM | MATCHNOMATCH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 18961-060 | 900000021 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 18961-060 | 900000021 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 22873 | 900000028 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 22873 | 900000028 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 | N |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 | N |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 | Y |

though everything in both the tables match, I am getting 292 entries as output with even N as output in matchnomatch column. What is the best way to do this?

### I am expecting following output alone
ExpectedOutput:

| A.PP | A.CP | A.LINNUM | B.PP | B.CP | B.LINNUM | MATCHNOMATCH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 18961-060 | 900000021 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 18961-060 | 900000021 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 22873 | 900000028 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 22873 | 900000028 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 | 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 | Y |

If the linnum does not really match thought pp and cp match, it should give N. How can this be done in oracle sql.

Comment: Too much data, Could you perhaps share a few rows so that we can follow along, as well as the expected output?

Comment: It is unclear what you expect and what you're getting. Is the issue the # of rows returned, or that you see a mix of Y and N where you expect only Ys?

Comment: You have 2 rows with CP='23282-10' in each table. Your inner join criteria will match all these rows with records in another table. As a result, these would generate 2 * 2 = 4 rows.

You need to define how should rows in the tables matches when there are multiple rows with same PP and CP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` on all 3 columns and then check if a match was found in the `CASE` expression based on the existence of a joined row:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       CASE WHEN t2.pp IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS matchnomatch
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON     t1.pp = t2.pp
          AND t1.cp = t2.cp
          AND t1.linnum = t2.linnum;
```

Which outputs:

| PP | CP | LINNUM | MATCHNOMATCH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 18961-060 | 900000021 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 22873 | 900000028 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000038 | Y |
| 4610-A4N3C-K0235 | 23282-10 | 900000044 | Y |

Or, if you only want the rows from `table1` and no duplicates if there are multiple matches between `table1` and `table2` then select only from `table1` and use `EXISTS` to check for matches in `table2`:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM   table2 t2
                         WHERE  t1.pp = t2.pp
                         AND    t1.cp = t2.cp
                         AND    t1.linnum = t2.linnum)
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END AS matchnomatch
FROM   table1 t1;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs the same as above.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ukw5rD1d)

Comment: thanks a lot @fiddle. 2nd query helped me for the output that I needed

Answer (score -1):

Some comments on your query:

```
select a.pp,a.cp,a.linnum,b.pp,b.pp,b.linnum,
case when a.pp=b.pp and a.cp=b.cp and a.linnum=b.linnum then 'Y' Else 'N' end matchnomatch
from tt1 a inner join tt2 b
on (a.pp=b.pp and a.cp=b.cp);
```

Every line it gives back must have the pp and cp the same in bth tables, so displaying them both is useless. And comparing them in your case statement is also useless.
If you want to have tjust the rows where linnum is the same, then use this

```
select a.pp,a.cp,a.linnum
from tt1 a inner join tt2 b
on (a.pp=b.pp and a.cp=b.cp and a.linnum=b.linnum);
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than joining on the linenum - and assuming that if the linenums are different it won't affect the order within the pp,cp group (such that if you had three rows in one group with linenums of 1, 2, 3 in table1, it wouldn't end up being 1, 5, 3 in table2) - labelling the rows with a row number and using that in the join condition of a full outer join could give you what you want, e.g.:

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT '4610-A4N3C-K0235' pp, '18961-060' cp, 900000021 linenum FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '4610-A4N3C-K0235' pp, '18961-060' cp, 900000028 linenum FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '4610-A4N3C-K0235' pp, '18961-060' cp, 900000038 linenum FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '4610-A4N3C-K0235' pp, '18961-060' cp, 900000044 linenum FROM dual),
     table2 AS (SELECT '4610-A4N3C-K0235' pp, '18961-060' cp, 900000021 linenum FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '4610-A4N3C-K0235' pp, '18961-060' cp, 900000028 linenum FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '4610-A4N3C-K0235' pp, '18961-060' cp, 900000038 linenum FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT '4610-A4N3C-K0235' pp, '18961-060' cp, 900000044 linenum FROM dual),
         t1 AS (SELECT pp, cp, linenum, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pp, cp ORDER BY linenum) rn FROM table1),
         t2 AS (SELECT pp, cp, linenum, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pp, cp ORDER BY linenum) rn FROM table2)
SELECT t1.pp,
       t1.cp,
       t1.linenum,
       t2.pp,
       t2.cp,
       t2.linenum,
       CASE WHEN t1.linenum = t2.linenum THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END matching
FROM   t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.pp = t2.pp AND t1.cp = t2.cp AND t1.rn = t2.rn;
```